# Using environment variables with Node.js

Tags: environment-variables, nginx, nodejs, javascript

I am trying to prepare my app for production on a ubuntu running nginx. I have been using the dotenv npm package during development, but need a more stable and secure method for production. I have added the variables to /etc/environment because I would like them to exist in the app permanently.

Can someone explain to me how to access them from my server.js file?

I have tried using process.env.variable and $variable but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply: `source /etc/environment`

Now run your application from the same shell, and `process.env.foo` should pick up the `foo` variable if it was declared in your `env` file.

---

You may also try running the application in a docker container and the `docker-run` command has an option `--env-file=...` where you can supply an environment file such as `/etc/environment`.